# Hola, tengo este fragmento de codigo y quiero que al hacer doble click no aparezcan dos veces los datos que se envian

Tags: javascript, html, dom

El codigo no es mio, me lo dieron en el trabajo para que le haga ese cambio y la verdad es que recien estoy empezando y me cuesta mucho trabajar sobre un codigo ya escrito, no se donde hacer el cambio exactamente y tampoco como, asi que si alguien me puede dar una solucion se lo agradezco.
Al hacer un solo click se emvia la informacion correcta aunque se vuelva a hacer click, pero si haces doble click asi si es cuando se envia de manera doble la info.

Puedo enviar la totalidad del codigo si fuera necesario.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var Provincia, Localidad;
CargarProvincias();
$("#ProvinciaDescrip").change(function () {
    Provincia = $("#ProvinciaDescrip option:selected").text();
    CargarLocalidades();
})
$("#Buscar").click(function () {
    Buscar();
})
function Buscar() {
    desabledBtn();
    var calles = "";
    var calleNro1 = 0;
    $("#agencias-gallery").remove();
    $("#slider-contenedor1").append('\
    <div id="agencias-gallery"  class"flickity-viewport" style="height: auto;"</div>');
    Localidad = $("#LocalidadDescrip option:selected").val();
    Provincia = $("#ProvinciaDescrip option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebServices/Agencias.asmx/BuscarAgencia",
        data: "{'Provincia':'" + Provincia + "','Localidad':'" + Localidad + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data.d);
            jsonObj = jsonObj.Table;
            $(jsonObj).each(function () {
                var a = this.EntregaDomicilio;
                var b = this.RetiraDomicilio;
                var c = this.EsCentroDistribucion;
                var d = this.EsReceptora;
                var e = this.EsEmisora;
                var f = this.AceptaTarjeta;
                var g=this.Horarios
                if (a == true) {
                    a = "si";
                }
                else {
                    a = "no";
                }
                if (b == true) {
                    b = "si";
                }
                else {
                    b = "no";
                }
                if (c == true) {
                    c = "si";
                }
                else {
                    c = "no";
                }
                if (d == true) {
                    d = "si";
                }
                else {
                    d = "no";
                }
                if (e == true) {
                    e = "si";
                }
                else {
                    e = "no";
                }
                if (f == true) {
                    f = "si";
                }
                else {
                    f = "no";
                }
                calles = this.Calle;
                calleNro1 = this.CalleNro;
                if(g!=""){
                $("#agencias-gallery").append('<div class="gallery-cell">\
                                                    <h2 class="dire2">' + this.ProvinciaDescrip + ' - ' + this.LocalidadDescrip + '</h2>\
                                                    <h2 class="dire"><div class="ubic"></div>'+ this.Calle + ' ' + this.CalleNro + '</h2>\
                                                        <div class="tela"></div><p class="pagencia"><span>: '+ this.TelCodArea + '-' + this.Telefono + '<br></p>\
                                                        <div class="hora"></div><p class="pagencia"><span>: '+ g + ' </span><br><br>\
                                                        Entrega a domicilio: '+ a + ' <br>\
                                                        Retira en domicilio: '+ b + ' <br>\
                                                        Ctro de Distribución: '+ c + ' <br>\
                                                        Recibe Cargas: '+ d + ' <br>\
                                                        Envia Cargas: ' + e + ' <br>\
                                                        Acepta Tarjeta: '+ f + ' \
                                                    </p>\
                                                </div>')
                }
                                            else{
                                                   $("#agencias-gallery").append('<div class="gallery-cell">\
                                                    <h2 class="dire2">' + this.ProvinciaDescrip + ' - ' + this.LocalidadDescrip + '</h2>\
                                                    <h2 class="dire"><div class="ubic"></div>'+ this.Calle + ' ' + this.CalleNro + '</h2>\
                                                        <div class="tela"></div><p class="pagencia"><span>: '+ this.TelCodArea + '-' + this.Telefono + '</span><br><br>\
                                                        Entrega a domicilio: '+ a + ' <br>\
                                                        Retira en domicilio: '+ b + ' <br>\
                                                        Ctro de Distribución: '+ c + ' <br>\
                                                        Recibe Cargas: '+ d + ' <br>\
                                                        Envia Cargas: ' + e + ' <br>\
                                                        Acepta Tarjeta: '+ f + ' \
                                                    </p>\
                                                </div>')
                                            }


            });
            var callenro = 0;
            if (calleNro1 == "S/N") {
                callenro = 0
            }
            else {
                callenro = calleNro1
            }
            //$("#mapas").attr({ 'src': 'Mapas.html?Provincia=' + Provincia + '&Localidad=' + Localidad });

            var address = Localidad + " " + Provincia + " Argentina";
            var lat = '';
            var long = '';

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                    'app_id': 'hC26tnFWIZmczwAtkSzo',
                    'app_code': '_UFRNuJNHTr9NwunFji6vg',
                    'searchtext': address,
                    'no_annotations': 1
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                statusCode: {
                    200: function (response) {  // success
                        lat = response.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude;
                        long = response.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude;

                        $("#mapas").attr({ 'src': 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=14tw3Ro5pBU7qFr9RT_ky-Wwx7RGsu5Mp&ll=' + lat + ',' + long + '&z=13' });
                    },
                    402: function () {
                        //
                    }
                }
            });
            

            //$("#mapas").attr({ 'src': 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDINjBbjAerx9WLVxfNujytcaJlHcX2R8c&q="' + Provincia + "," + Localidad + "," + calles + "," + callenro });
            

            $('#agencias-gallery').flickity({
                // options
                cellAlign: 'center',
                contain: true
            });
        },
        error: function () {
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Podrias desabilitar el voton por un tiempo ejemplo 5 segundos o hasta que la información se haya enviado.  No estoy seguro si al escuchar el evento de doble click se anularía el segundo click pero puedes investigar

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos lo que intentastes? Ademas, agrega que parte no entiendes para ayudarte

Comment: @juanRivera no he intentado nada porque no se como hacerlo, se me ocurrio desabilitar el boton por unos segundos pero no se como ni en que funcion ponerlo

Comment: @christian tambien pense en eso pero no se como hacerlo ni en que funcion ponerlo.

Comment: Cuál es el código de la función `Buscar()`? A esa función te refieres?

Comment: @Bicho, no podria hacerlo en el onclick donde llamo a la funcion buscar, osea antes de que busque??

Comment: Puedes limpiar el contenedor en donde estás mostrando la información antes de llamar a la función `Buscar()` con `$('#id_contenedor').val('');`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres deshabilitar el boton solo haz una funcion y llamala cuando la necesites

```
function desabledBtn(){
    let btn = document.getElementById("boton")
    btn.disabled=true;
}
```

luego para implementarlo lo harias en la funcion *AJAX* como no esta la funcion *Buscar()*, voy a hacerlo con la de `CargarProvicias()`

```
function CargarProvincias() {
    $.ajax({
        ....
        beforeSend: desabledBtn(), //deshabilitamos el boton al hacer la peticion
        success: function(){
            ....
             //habilitamos el boton cuando todo haya salido bien
             let btn = document.getElementById("boton")
             btn.disabled=false;        
        }
    })
})
```

La funcion `desabledBtn()` la puedes implemenar en el codigo sin tenerlo en la funcion, pero puedes dejarlo en caso hagas otra cosa al deshabilitar el boton, or ejemplo cambiar el color, la opaciad etc

Comment: Podrias mostrarme exactamnete como quedaria en mi funcion cargarProvincias? no se en que orden ponerlo, nunca he usado ajax.

Comment: No lo vas a implementar en cargar provincias (o al menos que quieras que el botón no cumpla su funcion) deberías implementarlo, según yo, en la función Buscar ya que ahí es donde se hace click al botón

Comment: te dejo un parte de buscar(), no entra toda en el comentario, beforeSend: desabledBtn() iria justoabajo de ajax y btn.disabled=false despues de success?
`function Buscar() {
        var calleNro1 = 0;
        $("#agencias-gallery").remove();
        $("#slider-contenedor1").append('\
        <div id="agencias-gallery"  class"flickity-viewport" style="height: auto;"</div>');
        Localidad = $("#LocalidadDescrip option:selected").val();
        Provincia = $("#ProvinciaDescrip option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
          ..
            success: function (data) {`
@christian

Comment: Exacto pero lo del btn va adentro del succes, te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y pongas el código de Buscar

Comment: Ahi segui tu consejo y subi la funcion buscar! se que es mucho pedir pero si lo puedes volver a ver te lo agradeceria

Comment: Ok en un momento edito mi respuesta